# Why \ref displays the label itself rather than the number

Tags: cross-referencing, ref

I met a strange problem.

If a have a label `\label{fig:Name}`. The cross referencing code `\ref{fig:Name}` cannot show the proper number. `1` for example, but the label `fig:Name` itself. And the label is already in the label list.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Are you by chance in some draft mode?

Comment: Where did you place the `\label`? It has to be inside or after the caption. Do you get any errors or warnings in the `.log` file?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of code which can be compiled as is for reproducing the erroneous/undesired behavior?